# how to find MD5 checksum of conda-forge packages

Tags: anaconda, checksum, md5sum, conda-forge

I am trying to download jaydebeapi package from conda-forge (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jaydebeapi/files). But I could not find md5 checksum value for this package to verify against my downloads.

Is md5 checksum values available anywhere in anaconda repository/conda-forge; Or any other option to verify downloads from these websites ?

Server does not have internet connectivity, hence doing offline installation after downloading the package.

Thanks,

Comment: try `conda search --info <pkg>`. It will list the file name plus md5sums. You can export as json and then verify, e.g. Not sure whether there is an easier approach.

Comment: if you don't want to rely on conda, you can do get it via web api: https://api.anaconda.org/docs#!/package/get_dist_owner_login_package_name_version_basename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checksum value is available in the information tab (click on small circle near to the filename).
[image]

conda search --info  also provides the details, but i could run it only after downloading and updating local repo.